# Why PageSpeed Insights do a "redirect"?

Tags: next.js, google-pagespeed

When measuring our page speed, i.e. this https://tiket.hu/buyTicket/nagybojti-lelkinap-2021

Google show not this but our home page as rendered page. But we do not redirect. Then why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site redirects to the home page on first visit.

If you then revisit the page it will stay on the correct page.

After a quick look around it appears that if you haven't already set "tempUserUuid" in local storage before you visit the page it redirects (as when I deleted this it redirected again).

This is probably why you haven't spotted the issue at your side.

As Page Speed Insights always runs from a clean cache (as if it was a first time visitor) this is why you are seeing this behaviour from PSI.